# Javascript/jQuery - Using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

If a div doesn't exist on a page, and I mean really not even in the code;  I'm not just talking about display:none.  How can I check if it exist on the page or not?

I'm using google maps, and when you click on a marker to see the info window, a div gets added to the source code; but prior to that there is no div in the actual source code.

I'm looking for some help with javascript/jquery, to detect that the div was added to the source code. Then search for that div, that has another div inside it with a class of 'button'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var button = $(".button");
    var buttonlength = button.length;

    if (buttonlength) {
        console.log("div exist");

        button.on("click", function(){
            $(".info").css("display", "block");
        });

    } else {
        console.log("div does not exist");
    }
});
```

The on click event doesn't work because I feel like the DOM doesn't realize that the div is on the page after clicking on the map marker.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is live, so just trying to get the element from the DOM and checking for length should do

```
if ( $('#element_id').length ) {
    // element exists
}
```

That checks for an element existance in the DOM *when you run it*.

**EDIT:**

Seems like what you're really looking for is a delegated event handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
        $('.info').css('display','block');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with some code, using your advice.  But still seem to be having trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
jQuery.exists = function('.button') {return ($('.button').length > 0);}

$(document).ready(function(){

    //var button = $(".button");
    //var buttonlength = button.length;

    if ($.exists('.button')) {
        console.log("div exist");

        $(".button").on("click", function(){
            $(".info").css("display", "block");
        });

    } else {
        console.log("div does not exist");
    }
});
```